# jQuery UI: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I've spent way too much time looking for help on Google and trying to fix it myself.

The code that's causing all trouble looks something like this:

```
$("#nameBox").dialog({
    "modal":        false,
    "autoOpen":     false,
    "resizable":    false,
    "height":       "auto",
    "width":        350,
    "open":         function(){$("input[name='name']",this).val('');},
    "buttons":      {"Save":function(){
        var current_user = $("input[name='name']",this).val();
    }}
});
```

On IE8, I get a message '**Object doesn't support this property or method**', which apparently was caused by this line:

```
        var current_user = $("input[name='name']",this).val();
```

What confuses me is that the dialog opens, meaning that this code get executed successfully even though they both use the same method:

```
    "open":         function(){$("input[name='name']",this).val('');},
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Same result with: "input[name=name]"  ???

Comment: You're using `this` as the context for the selector. I'd guess that the value of `this` isn't the same when those two lines of code are being executed; try adding some statements to find out what `this` is at those points, and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `this` is not set to the same object in both cases.

Try the following code in your favorite javascript console:

```
var test = { "prop1": function(){console.log(this);}, "prop2":{"Save":function(){console.log(this);}}, "prop3": 10}
```

And then run `test.prop1()` and `test.prop2.Save()`. You will see that in the first try you get logged the Object `test`, and in the second example you will get logged the inner Object `prop2`.

You can read a great article about it [here](http://doctrina.org/Javascript-Function-Invocation-Patterns.html#ci)